# Why a jump cannot be made from the inside to the outside of a finally block?

Tags: c#, finally

Why a jump(`break`, `continue`, `goto`, `return`) cannot be made from the inside to the outside of a `finally` block (except via `throw`)?

Comment: It is a rule: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0157

Comment: Probably related to the fact that a finally may execute after a throw, return etc in the try block

Comment: Not permitted by the CLR, every language must observe that restriction in their syntax.  This exists primarily because the code in the finally clause can still execute, even though the method execution was interrupted by an exception and no longer returns normally.  Such code is also non-abortable, important for example for a using statement.  Features that would be extraordinarily hard to implement if the control flow wasn't limited.

Comment: Maybe you're intested in this answer I gave ... there is a [workaround possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61674051/1016343), however it's up to you if you want to do it that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can anyone explain the technical reason?

No, because there is no technical reason. It would have been perfectly possible to design language semantics that permitted a branch that leaves a finally, and other languages do allow it. There could be some small difficulties, as the rules for where branches may appear in IL are different for try-protected regions, but these are easily managed.

C# disallows this behaviour because the language would be worse if it had this feature. Branching out of a finally is a bad programming practice and should be disallowed.

Think about it this way. If the finally is running because of an exception, then hijacking the control flow associated with that exception is a bad idea; the continuation of the finally should either be implementation-defined behaviour, if the exception is unhandled, in which case it can do anything, or it should be the catch block which handles the exception. The only way to "cancel" an "in-flight"  exception is to throw another exception and allow it to be handled instead.

And if the finally is not running because of an exception, then you can put the control flow you want after the try-finally block.

Therefore, allowing branches out of a finally is either wrong or unnecessary. Since there is no need for branching out of a finally, and doing so ever is a bad idea, it should be made illegal.

Comment: Thank you. Very good answer. Specially this part: "If the finally is running because of an exception, then hijacking the control flow associated with that exception is a bad idea"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're trying to `return` inside a finally, you're getting the error

> CS0157 Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause

But Besides Eric's excellent answer, and I completely agree with his opinion, there is still a **workaround** possible:

```
void Main() {
    MyFunction();
}

void MyFunction()
{

    void FinalActions() // local function used in the finally block below
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (i>10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("more than 10 ... ending.");

                // this  RETURNS  from the local function and hence ends the finally block
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // the try-catch-finally block where we're using FinalActions()...
    try {
        // whatever you want to do here
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // whatever you want to do here
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally {
        FinalActions(); // just invoke it, the rest is done there
    }

}
```

[Try it as .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lu2D2v)

The **local function `FinalActions()`** ends as soon as `i>10` by returning using the keyword `return` - note this code is only to show you technically what you can do, you wouldn't program it this way (in the for loop you would just say `i <= 10`).

And of course, the other keywords

> break, continue, goto

are also allowed **within the context of the local function `FinalActions()`**, although I do not encourage to use `goto`.

---

Note: Older versions of the C# compiler do not support local functions, you have to use a current version.